# CSS white-space pre-wrap rules for lone carriage return

Tags: html, css, newline

Is it valid to put lone carriage-return characters into a HTML block formatted with `white-space: pre-wrap`?

I've got an application which is receiving a SOAP message, and logging the message to a file.  Our logging code has always stripped new-line characters so on Unix, this is a one-line log entry.  The incoming message is windows format CRLF though, so after stripping the new-line, I'm left with lone carriage returns.

The log viewer screen on the application shows a table with the log entries having `white-space: pre-wrap` formatting.  On my browser at least, this looks great, with lone carriage returns working just the same as a new-line or CRLF.

Is this reliable behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, it's valid. Using `white-space: pre-wrap;` is exactly the same as using `<pre>`, except that it will naturally wrap lines according to the boundaries of its parent.

However, you should consider making sure your CSS is cross-browser compliant.

```
#log {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* CSS3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

You can also use `white-space: pre;` if you want line to push the boundaries of its parent to keep everything in the output on a single line